# In a list (2010), can I have a Choice type field that can dynamically be filled as users add new values to that field (if it didn't already exist)?

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, custom-list, choice-field

A list of projects are in the Choice field already. As new projects are started a user (without designer access) wants to add a new project and in the future be able to select it from the drop down, not type it in every single time.

I can only use web-based editing. Would someone need Designer to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a lookup list instead of a choice column.  So a new project would be a new item in the Projects list, and the lookup would pick it up with no extra effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can add/remove Choices by editing the column in **List Settings**.

As far as I know you need some customization to support permanent insertion beside this. For example you could inject a button which adds choices with JavaScript and Client Object Model.